# PostgreSQL SSH port forwarding via Windows/PuTTY

Tags: postgresql, ssh, putty

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 running on a Linux VPS, and I need to be able to connect to it over SSH from both Linux and Windows clients. (I will later need to connect to multiple servers, and so that all clients use the same port numbers, I'm forwarding to port 5551 for the first server, then I will use 5552, 5553, etc.)

From a Linux client I just run `ssh -fNg -L 5551:localhost:5432 user@remote1.com` and connect to localhost:5551 with PGAdmin3 or any other client app. Works great.

On Windows, I'm using PuTTY and Pageant. I got the connection to user@remote1.com via terminal working, then I went to the SSH Tunnels and added `L5432 localhost:5551`. Terminal connection still works, but when I try to connect with PGAdmin3 to localhost:5551 I get an error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274AD/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5551?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. Like many things, this is obvious in hindsight. I had things backward in the SSH Tunnels setup in PuTTY. It needs to be `L5551 remote1.com:5432`

Comment: Could I see you full PuTTY setup? Struggling with the same problem

Comment: Sorry, but I can't. When I have to use a Windows machine now I use SSL via Git Bash. I haven't touched Putty in years.